# @login_required decorator is not working (Django)

Tags: python, django

I am trying to build a social media like thing and have created the login and signup feature.
For home page I have added login_required decorator and even added LOGIN_URL in settings.py but still I am able to access the home page without login i.e login_required decorator is not doing its job.
Here is my view function code

```
@login_required
def home(request):
return render(request, 'home/home.html')
```

Here is my code in settings.py

```
LOGIN_URL = '/login'
```

content of urls.py(account app)

```
urlpatterns = [
path('login/', views.login_view, name="login"),
path('create/', views.create_view, name="create",),
]
```

content of urls.py(home app)

```
urlpatterns = [
path('', views.welcome, name="welcome"),
path('home/', views.home, name="home"),
]
```

Can anyone find out what might be the problem?

Comment: Do you have an error message?

Comment: I don't see any error message :(

Comment: obviously man. I have included it

Comment: I'm sorry for this dumb questions, I try to understand.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was that I had still not created logout function. So the account was logged in and that's why login required was not working. It's simple.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure you have imported it: `from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required`
2. Try to add: [LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#login-redirect-url)
3. Try: `@login_required(login_url='login')`

Comment: I have imported and there is no error also.

Comment: What is your login routing in urls.py.

Comment: I have added it in the question now. check it out

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please check it out.

Comment: tried everything you mentioned. I am still able to access the home page without login :(

Comment: Show me your auth function, please.

Comment: Are you sure you're not logged in already? Also instead of using `@login_required` check authentication manually with something like `if not request.user.is_authenticated: raise PermissionDenied` to rule out that the problem lies with the decorator

Comment: Hey, yes the problem was that I had still not created logout function. So the account was logged in and that's why login required was not working. Thanks for helping me out 